# Require the textarea to be filled in when certain option is selected

Tags: javascript

I need the textarea to be filled when "Other" is selected.
This is what I have, I thought it will work.  But nothing shows up when other is selected and textarea is left blank.

html:

```
<form onsubmit="return validation()">
<span>Reason for inquiry: <span>
    <select style="color:black" name="reasons">
        <option value="catering">Catering</option>
        <option value="private party">Private Party</option>
        <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
        <option id="selectedOther" value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validation(){
    otherInquiry()
}

function otherInquiry(){
    var x = document.getElementById("selectedOther").value;
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("select") == x){
            if(document.getElementById("txtArea").value == ""){
                alert("Please tell us your reason of inquiry")
            }
        return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a **list** of nodes. `x` is a **string**. Comparing a list against a string will always be `false`. Maybe you want to take a look at [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801/218196)

Comment: Thanks, that fix the issue.